# Returning the array before the function is complete & Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to return the array 'self.results' with all the arrays pushed in, which is after the self.yelpResults is completed. I want to use the returned array in another function. For now, self.parsedYelpArray is suppose to accept that array.

I am having trouble getting the self.results return all the arrays that are being pushed in. Instead, it asynchronously push the original empty array into the self.parsedYelpArray function.

How do I resolve this?

This is the code in my controller:

```
self.MapRouteArray = CompileMapArray.compileRoutes(data);
self.yelpResults = CompileYelpResults.compileYelp(self.MapRouteArray);
self.parsedYelpArray = ParsingYelpResults.parsingData(self.yelpResults);
```

And, these are the relevant services:

```
 .service('CompileMapArray', function () {
        var self = this;
        self.MapRouteArray = [];
        self.compileRoutes = function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.response.route[0].leg[0].maneuver.length; i += 2) {
                self.MapRouteArray.push(data.response.route[0].leg[0].maneuver[i].position.latitude + ',' + data.response.route[0].leg[0].maneuver[i].position.longitude);
            }
            return self.MapRouteArray;
        };
    })

    .service('CompileYelpResults', function (YelpResource) {
        var self = this;
        self.results = [];

        self.compileYelp = function (mapArray) {
            for (var j = 0; j < mapArray.length; j++) {
                YelpResource.getListings({term: self.yelpSearch, ll: mapArray[0]}, function (response) {
                    self.results.push(response.businesses);
                            console.log(self.results);
                });
            }
            return self.results;
        };
    })

.service('ParsingYelpResults', function () {
        var self = this;
        self.parsingData = function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        };
    });
```

Comment: you can pass `parsingData` as a callback to `compileYelp` and use result in there.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with callback. Do you think you can explain it a little bit more? Thanks @iroegbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return from an asynchronous function; you'll always get unreliable results from that, you need to pass in a callback function that handles whatever operation you want at the end of your async... Like:

```
.service('CompileYelpResults', function (YelpResource) {
    var self = this;
    self.results = [];

    self.compileYelp = function (mapArray, callbackFn) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mapArray.length; j++) {
            YelpResource.getListings({term: self.yelpSearch, ll: mapArray[0]}, function (response) {
                self.results.push(response.businesses);
                        console.log(self.results);
            });
        }
        callbackFn(self.results);
    };
});
```

Then call the function with a callback function like so:

```
var parsed = CompileYelpResults.compileYelp(self.MapRouteArray, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This goes for all your asynchronous functions.

Relating to your comment the callback function you pass as second parameter to `compileYelp` takes the place of `parsingData`, so whatever processing you want to do with the `results` will be in the body of the callback function. It gives extra advantage in that you can use the results whichever way you like. For example.

```
var logged = CompileYelpResults.compileYelp(self.MapRouteArray, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});

var stringified = CompileYelpResults.compileYelp(self.MapRouteArray, function(result) {
    JSON.stringify(result);
});
```

Comment: Hi @iroegbu - Thanks for your response. This is very helpful. I'm a bit confused about the callbackFn. How is it defined in the self.compileYelp function? In the parsed variable, what is the callback function? The function(result) part? is the self.MapRouteArray still referring to the mapArray in the self.compileYelp function?

Comment: See update, pass `callbackFn` as parameter to compileYelp. Then `compileYelp` calls callbackFn when `results` is ready. The callback should have the same function as your `parsingData` function.

Comment: Thanks so much @iroegbu! I finally figured got it to work. I had to set a timeout with the callback function, as the result was not returning on the first instance, but does so on the second and so forth turn.